# Using Arduino Libraries with AVR-G++

Tags: c++, c, arduino, avr, avrdude

Is there a simple way to use libraries intended for the Arduino IDE with the C and assembly code I write for AVR-G++/AVR-GCC?

I'm trying to use the [Adafruit Wave Shield library](http://code.google.com/p/wavehc/), but simply including the header and cpp files don't do much good. Can I compile it somehow and link it to my C code? Or perhaps just find a way to make it compile with my C code.

Currently, when I try to do something simple like:

```
#include "WaveHC/WaveHC.h"    
SdReader card;
card.init();
```

I am greeted with:

```
70: undefined reference to `SdReader::init(unsigned char)'
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this [makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to compile all my code for Arduino without using IDE. You can use both Arduino libs as well as user libs in this makefile.

**Update**: There is also a [tutorial](http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/compiling-arduino-sketches-using-makefile), which explains how to setup and use this makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You can build the Arduino code with [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake). I have built largish Arduino projects without using the IDE this way. You can use whatever tools you want to build the Arduino code, it is just a C/C++ library. You mainly need to make sure you have all of the preprocessor settings right (F_CPU? Maybe some others).

*[Build using Cmake](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/CmakeBuild)* might help you. Basically, I would make a library file for the Arduino library, a library file for the [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) library, and an EXE file for your code.